# How to use sqlcmd to create file names for output based on the day of the week or the date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL agent job that queries the database and exports the results into a csv file.
It needs to run daily and The output file (Output.csv) gets overwritten everytime the job runs. Is there a way to create new files instead of overwriting? Say monday.csv, tuesday.csv etc or maybe {date}.csv

This is the command:

```
SQLCMD -S SQL-CLUST1 -Q "SELECT * FROM TABLE" -o "\\\PATH\output.csv" -W -s","
```

Step type: Operating system (CmdExec)

Run as : SQL Proxy

*Note: The output file and append output to existing file is unavailable in the advanced tab.*

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server? SQL is a language, not a DBMS.

Comment: @Colin Yes its MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below [script](https://web.archive.org/web/20151226144958/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bill/archive/2009/02/13/file.aspx) will help you. Just save it as a `.bat` file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set timehour=%time:~0,2%
sqlcmd -S SQL-CLUST1 -E -Q "SELECT * FROM TABLE" -o report-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%-%timehour: =0%%time:~3,2%.txt
```

If you have `xp_cmdshell` enabled, then it is much easier :

```
DECLARE       @sqlCommand   VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE       @filePath     VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE       @fileName     VARCHAR(100)
 
SET    @filePath = 'C:\Temp\'
 
SET    @fileName = 'Output_' +
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + '_' +
         CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '_' +
         CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '.txt'
 
SET    @sqlCommand =
       'SQLCMD -S server_name -E -d master -q "select @@servername" -o "' +
       @filePath + @fileName +
       '" -h-1'
 
 
PRINT       @sqlCommand
 
--EXEC   master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCommand
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another step after that SQLCMD that performs renaming your outputfile in another CmdExec step type:

ren myfile.csv myfile_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%*%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%*%time:~6,5%.csv